# PyTorch: nn.Identity() vs. lambda x: x : Can they be used interchangeably?

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, torch

Can I use a lambda function, `lambda x: x` instead of [torch.nn.Identity](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Identity.html)? And does this differ depending on where in a model this identity is placed? My guess would be that pytorch might not know how to deal with a lambda function intermingled with torch.nn.Modules, and that it can slow down training.

---

Why I'm asking: Out of curiosity. The function is so [simple](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/58d1b3639bc07f9519de18e5a18e575f260c7eeb/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L12-L32) that I find it unlikely that a bug will ever sneak in there in a pytorch release, so there doesn't really seem to be a reason for avoiding it.

Comment: nn.Identity() do nothing and return the original value.

It is useless when training a model. It is a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a difference, but I can't exclude that there are cases where it makes a difference.

Code to test it:

```
import torch
import torchvision.ops
import timeit

def enc_function(x):
    return x

encoders = [lambda x: x, torch.nn.Identity(), enc_function]
encoder_names = ["lambda", "torch.nn.Identity", "def-function"]
encoder = lambda x: x  # or torch.nn.Identity
model = torchvision.ops.MLP(10, [10, 10, 10])
input = torch.rand(1000, 10)
target = torch.rand(1000, 10)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)


def optimize(encoder):
    output_1 = model(encoder(input))
    output_2 = model(encoder(output_1))
    loss = torch.mean((output_2 - target) ** 2)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

assert torch.cuda.is_available()

for i, enc in enumerate(encoders):
    print("encoder ", encoder_names[i], ", result: ",
          timeit.repeat(lambda: optimize(enc), number=500))
```

Output:

```
encoder  lambda , result:  [0.8841933999992762, 0.8926422090007691, 0.858818758999405, 0.8667592129986588, 0.8647603850004089]
encoder  torch.nn.Identity , result:  [0.8829251480001403, 0.8796868690005795, 0.8737372629984748, 0.8735423289999744, 0.8724708320005448]
encoder  def-function , result:  [0.8849818350008718, 0.866065903001072, 0.8640658660006011, 0.8650053179990209, 0.913033455999539]
```